# Azure Blob or File Share, which one is best for SQL Backup?

Tags: sql-server, azure, cloudberry

I have a VM in Azure which is running SQL 2012. It has around 250GB of Databases. Currently the backups are being written to Azure Blob Storage which is mounted in the SQL VM using CloudBerry Drive Server app. I want to use Azure File Share instead to avoid the dependency of Cloudberry which makes lot of issues. Can you please tell me the advantages / disadvantages of this change and cost effectiveness?

Comment: You can remove cloudberry from the equation and use PowerShell to take the back-up and then push the backup (in blocks) up to Blob Storage.  I'd stick with Blob Storage for this use case.  Here is MS docs that describes Files API and the difference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/file-service-rest-api

Answer (score 0):

I think better stay with Azure Blob Storage with avoiding CloudBerry,
because starting with SQL Server 2012 SP1 CU2, you can write SQL Server backups directly to the Azure Blob storage service with a lot of other benefits and it can be done via simple configuration. At my current job we are doing it in that way ([more details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/virtual-machines-windows-use-storage-sql-server-backup-restore)).

Answer (score 0):

Using Cloudberry Drive as backups destination is not the best scenario for this app, I doubt it was developed for such cases Better to write directly to Azure Block Blobs or to use backup apps to do the same thing.